# Compare the difference of two array index by index

Tags: php

I want to know how can I compare two arrays if there's a differences between their values in each indexes. I have this two arrays for example.

```
$arr1 = ["0"=>"A", "1"=>"B", "2"=>"C", "3"=>"A"]..
$arr2 = ["0"=>"A", "1"=>"C", "2"=>"C", "3"=>"A"]..
```

The result that I want to get would be 1 because only index 1 is not equal with the index 1 of the second array.

I tried using *array_diff* but the result is always 0. I want to compare each array by indexes and values and return the number of differences on each.

Thank you

Comment: You can use for loop?

Comment: Do you want a new array that returns the difference or a simple 1? what if there are many different indexes?

Comment: i just want a simple 1. but if it's possible to return all differences it will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr1 = ["0"=>"A", "1"=>"B", "2"=>"C", "3"=>"A"];
$arr2 = ["0"=>"A", "1"=>"C", "2"=>"C", "3"=>"A"];
print_r(array_diff_assoc($arr1, $arr2)); // output: [1 => "B"]
```

Is this what you want? If you only need an index, you can do this

```
print_r(array_keys(array_diff_assoc($arr1, $arr2))); // output: [1]
```